# Gen. Solution for a 3x3 matrix with a single eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I have a matrix that I am trying to find a general solution a system $x'=Ax$ where A is the matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & -1 \\ -3 & 2 & 4\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
 and found that the matrix has a single eigenvalue, 2, with multiplicity 3.

I've seen plenty of examples of 3x3 matrices with an eigenvalue repeated twice but never three times.

I found that the general eigenvector is $$v=c\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
but I am at a lost as what to do next.

Comment: what do you mean by "solution of a matrix"?

Comment: Sorry, I left out what the system was: x' = Ax. I edited the question to include it.

Comment: You find matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1} A P = J$ is in Jordan form. Then you find $e^{Jt}$ where $t$ id the independent variable, finally your solution is $P e^{Jt} P^{-1} $

Comment: So you're solving for $x$? Shouldn't the answer just be $A^{-1}x'$ then?

Comment: @Akababa  the notation is consistent with a differential equation system. If that is true, the problem is not particularly difficult, as there is a single Jordan block

Comment: @trich42 What is the vector of $x'$ if you solvable for $x$? Or did you get general solution  in arbitrary $x'$?